# What is the difference between "next dev" and "next build + next start"

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, auth0

What is the difference between the Next.js commands `next dev` and `next build` + `next start`?

I have [read the docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/deployment) and know the basics, but I have a `fetch` (see below) that works when loading the page during `next dev`, but throws a connection refused error when loading the page during `next build` + `next start`.

**Error:**

> TypeError: fetch failed
> at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11118:11)
> at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {   cause: Error: connect
> ECONNREFUSED ::1:3000
> at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1300:16)
> at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
> errno: -4078,
> code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
> syscall: 'connect',
> address: '::1',
> port: 3000   } }

Screen shot for reference:

[image]

**Fetch:**

```
const getUser = async () => {
  const res = await fetch(`${process.env.AUTH0_BASE_URL}/api/auth/me`, {
    headers: {
      cookie: cookies().getAll().map(c => `${c.name}=${c.value}`).join(';') -- all cookies
    }
  })
  return await res.json()
}
```

Some additional info on the fetch can be found here: https://github.com/auth0/nextjs-auth0/issues/889

--

**Edit**: A few notes

- *next start* server: started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
- When looking in the browser's DevTools, it actually shows the getUser fetch request with a 200 OK response, which I found weird because the browser should not do the fetch at all (it is just on the server, right?). Screen shot:

[image]

Comment: as per [those docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started#manual-setup), `dev` runs things in development mode, `start` runs it in production mode. Dev as all kinds of niceties like "not minimizing code", having source maps, actually showing real errors instead of not revealing anything about what went wrong, etc. So if you get a "connection refused", it's a good bet that you've not set the appropriate CORS and CSP headers (which are strictly enforced in production).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Where do I set that? It is a Next.js app, hosted on Vercel. You mean there should be other headers added to the fetch, in production? If so, which? Thanks a million for any / all help.

Comment: PS: I guess the Vercel comment makes no difference when hosting it locally on localhost.

Comment: With that "it is just on the server, right?" we've entered "we don't know, you tell us" territory, because if you're seeing that in the browser then you've written code that gets bundled into your browser app and unless you show exactly what you've done, as [mcve], others can only guess at what's wrong (and guesses are not answers).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans The component with the fetch command in it has the `import server-only` package. I.e. it would throw an error message if it was run by the client.